# How to swap non-memory usb devices?

Tags: linux, usb, hotswapping

There are plenty of tools for umounting/mounting/automounting usb flash/pen drives/dongles/hard drives.  There's the *Device Notifier* on kde 4, for example.

But what about other devices like headphones, mice, keyboards, modems, etc?  A tool for doing this would be very handy.

Answer (score 3):

Those devices don't need mounting in the first place. Just pull them, and the underlying software stack should notice their removal and act appropriately. Unmounting is required in order to prevent damage to the underlying file system, but those are not storage devices.

Comment: Sometimes, doing this leads to issues.  When pulling out one device the other devices are unable to run on that usb port.

Comment: Then that would be a bug in the software stack and should be reported appropriately.