# Is there any actual harm to pulling the USB cable without disconnecting it first in the OS?

Tags: usb-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I unmount a USB drive before unplugging it?](https://superuser.com/questions/180722/should-i-unmount-a-usb-drive-before-unplugging-it)

I've never once in my life used a context menu or any other option to eject a USB device to disconnect it before pulling the plug. Am I being an idiot that is damaging my hardware?

[image: Ubuntu]
[image: OSX]
[image: Windows]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you may be [damaging the filesystem](https://superuser.com/questions/249519/how-to-swap-non-memory-usb-devices/249521#249521) on it.

Comment: By "damaging the file system" what is meant is that some files may not be completely written to disk and so the data may be corrupt (just like the power going out in the middle of saving a large document).